# React along with Stimulus js in Rails 6

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to use reactjs along with stimulusjs simultaneously in a an existing rails project?

This is not a coding specific question rather an architectural approach. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was asking myself this same question, and I found multiple resources.

The general idea on how I would prefer to use it is to use StimulusJS for most things, and where you need some powerlifting, mount React app and use it.

So what I will do here is list the resources that look helpful. Also, if I find time, I will try to update this answer with my use case and how I set this up with the mentioned resources below. (I might even create a blog post)

- Clay Murray's simple and awesome article (source: [DEV.to](https://dev.to/dropconfig/using-react-with-stimulus-js-di))
- David Guilfoyle's article (the author claims that this works with Turbolinks/Turbo as well) (source: [Medium](https://www.davedkg.com/stimulusjs-and-mounting-a-react-app/))
- DanBridges' article on using pre-built React components with Rails + StimulusJS (source: [a blog post](https://medium.com/parallel-thinking/rails-stimulus-react-59e54b633780))

Kudos go to the guys mentioned in the resources!